# $x^2-3$ is separable over $\mathbb Q$ but not separable over $F_2$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, separable-extension

$x^2-3=(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb Q$, so that part makes sense.

Now, when it says $x^2-3$ is a polynomial over $F_2$, I imagine it means all the coefficients are calculated mod $3$, so $p(x)=x^2-3=x^2$ in $F_2$.

$x^2$ doesn't have a second solution other than $0$ in $F_2=\{0,1,2\}$, but how do I know there is not some algebraic extension that it will have two roots in?

Also, is this discussion so far accurate?

Comment: Because a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ Distinct roots counting multaplicities. Moreover, any field is integral domain, so $x^n = 0$ if and only if $x=0$ in any field extension of any ground field.

Comment: Also, $F_2 = \{0,1\}$, not $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Thus, if you have a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ over a field $K$ that has $n$-roots in $K$ counting multaplicities, then if $K’$ is any exntesion of $K$, then if an element of $k\in K’$ is a root of $f$, then $k\in K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X^2-3$ in $F_2$ means that the coefficients are calculated $mod$  $2$ and not $mod$ $3$.

So $x^2-3=x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ mod $2$. You cannot have an extension with two different roots since the factorization over a field is unique. If you assume that the coefficient of higher degree  of factors of degree $>1$ is $1$.